# Array of ranges with numpy

Tags: python, optimization, numpy

I have the following array:

```
>>> x = numpy.array([2,4,2,3,1])
>>> x
array([2, 4, 2, 3, 1])
```

I would like an array of ranges of these values. I can create it like this:

```
>>> numpy.hstack( (numpy.arange(v) for v in x) )
array([0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0])
```

Given `x`, is there a faster way to generate this with numpy without having to use a for loop?

Comment: Looks like you found your solution... It would be interesting to know why you needed this, and why in this particular format.

Comment: I was working on speeding up the pycollada library (https://github.com/pycollada/pycollada). One of the geometry types in the collada format is called a polylist and it stores the vertex count of each polygon in an array like the ``x`` above. I needed the output range set to triangulate the polygons quickly in a single array.

Comment: You can see how it works in the triangleset() function I created in this commit: https://github.com/pycollada/pycollada/commit/71682c5506aa098c1105db850029d98e217f724b#L0R219

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out:

```
>>> x
array([2, 4, 2, 3, 1])
>>> ends = numpy.cumsum(x)
>>> ranges = numpy.arange(ends[-1])
>>> ranges = ranges - numpy.repeat(ends-x, x)
>>> ranges
array([0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0])
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this actually faster ?
I have a similar need, and

`concatenate([range(l, r) for l, r in array((left, right)).T])`

is twice as fast as

`range(end[-1]) + repeat(left + end, right-left)`

(where `end = cumsum(right - left)` just like yours).

(in my very short experience, repeat is very slow -- at least in python 3.6)